# R: how to highlight significant values in table output

Tags: r, output

I have 10 logistic regression output and I have used stargazer package  to create a table to put the 10 outputs together (with the following code and it looks like the following (a small portion of the table)).

```
 stargazer(result[[1]], result[[2]],result[[3]],result[[4]],result[[5]],result[[6]], 
  result[[7]],result[[8]],   result[[9]], result[[10]],
      dep.var.labels =c(" "),
      column.labels=c("dq(0)/bai(1)","dq(0)/bao(1)", "dq(0)/bei(1)", "dq(0)/pu(1)",
                      "bai(0)/bao(1)", "bai(0)/bei(1)", "bai(0)/pu(1)",
                      "bao(0)/bei(1)", "bao(0)/pu(1)", "bei(0)/pu(1)"),
      align=TRUE, out = "models.log.txt")
```

I am wondering if it would be possible to bold or  highlight the significant values in the output table. I have searched within the stargazer package, and it seems that it does not have such a function. 
 Would appreciate any insight.

```
   ============================================================================
                          Dependent variable:                                                        
         ------------------------------------------------------------------
     animal             3.079***    -4.240***     3.252***      
     habit              0.476      -6.850***       0.299      
     color             -3.063***      114.828      2.866**
```